# Copy Code inside the Code tag to Clipboard reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to `reactJS`. I am using `react-copy-to-clipboard` to copy my code to Clipboard. It was simple and awesome. Library Link: https://github.com/nkbt/react-copy-to-clipboard#usage

Here's the Code from their docs.

```
<CopyToClipboard text="Hello!">
  <button>Copy to clipboard</button>
</CopyToClipboard>
```

Here's the Code I tried

```
<Card>
    <div >
        <pre>
            <code>
                &lt;script src = "https://example.com/analaystics.js?analyticsId={this.state.tracking_id}"&gt;
                <br/>
                &lt;/script&gt;
            </code>
        </pre>
    </div>
</Card>
<CopyToClipboard text="&lt;script src = "https://example.com/analaystics.js?analyticsId={this.state.tracking_id}"&gt;
                    <br/>
                    &lt;/script&gt;">
    <Button type="primary" > Copy Code to Clipboard </Button>
</CopyToClipboard>,
```

I want to copy the content inside the `Code Tag` to the Clipboard. I tried this above way. But it shows error. How to make it. I found lot of answers but they showed to copy the Content in the text area. In my Case, it is the `code`. The Stored Content in Clipboard should be in Code format. Help me with some solutions.

Content to be Clipboard:

```
<script src = "https://example.com/analaystics.js?analyticsId=analyse-1e7pf1oipk8x04rj6">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, let's use one source of truth: get data that needs to be copied and shown from one place. As soon as it's a dynamically generated value - you can build it using a function.

At second - in order to get rid of errors while building `<script></script>` string you can split its generation to some substrings.

For example:

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {tracking_id: 123};

  getCode = () => `<script src="https://example.com/analaystics.js?analyticsId=${this.state.tracking_id}">
</script` + `>`

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>
          <code>
            {this.getCode()}
          </code>
        </pre>          
        <CopyToClipboard text={this.getCode()}>
          <button type="primary">Copy Code to Clipboard</button>
        </CopyToClipboard>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```